# Grant "Replicate Changes" permissions in Active Directory with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm creating a user in Active directory with PowerShell and need to assign it "Replicate Changes" rights.

I can't find anywhere online how to do this.

Comment: Hi @Richard Priddy, if the below answer is helped you please don't forget to **Upvote** and **Mark** it as accepted to close the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source: http://blog.kuppens-switsers.net/sharepoint/setting-replicating-directory-changes-using-powershell/

```
$Identity = "domain\account"

$RootDSE = [ADSI]"LDAP://RootDSE"
$DefaultNamingContext = $RootDse.defaultNamingContext
$ConfigurationNamingContext = $RootDse.configurationNamingContext
$UserPrincipal = New-Object Security.Principal.NTAccount("$Identity")

DSACLS "$DefaultNamingContext" /G "$($UserPrincipal):CA;Replicating Directory Changes"
DSACLS "$ConfigurationNamingContext" /G "$($UserPrincipal):CA;Replicating Directory Changes"
```

Comment: very awesome to know! maybe they can incorporate this with the autospinstaller script.

Comment: I don't suppose they will, as you will need some kind of admin access to AD, which you have on your own DEV machine (usually) but most likely not when installing the servers.